# Why the configuration for Act-as-taggable-on is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

Iam a Ruby on Rails beginner and implementing `ActsAsTaggable` functionality to my model.  I'm reading the act-as-taggable Github document, https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on, and I want to force tags to be saved lowercase i.e.  The instruction in the Configuration section says to add the following code in configuration

```
ActsAsTaggable.force_lowercase = true
```

I added the same code in my `$config/apllication.rb`

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true
  end
end
```

Now when t restart my server i get the following error:

```
`<class:Application>': uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::ActsAsTaggable (NameError)
```

Iam not able to figure out what am I doing worng. Please help me out to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you install the gem in your app? And where did you add this line? `ActsAsTaggable.force_lowercase = true `

Comment: Yupp the gem is installed and working properly. All i need is to save the tags in `lowercase`. I added this code in `config/application.rb` as i mentioned above. But its giving me the above mentioned issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? It works perfectly with no problems for me.